# Alter style of sudo command output

Tags: macos, sudo

Some of my build commands use the osx command `say` to notify me of progress whilst I continue to work. Generally, they use a gentle female voice, but when I run the command as `sudo` there is a rather gruff manly voice telling what's going on.

I think it would be useful if sudo commands had a similar visual clue to their output, so maybe the output could be prefixed with `*` or the colour changed to bright yellow or something alike. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Maybe I could create an alias for `sudo` which changes the colour of output, then continues to issue the sudo command - but I don't know how to get the colour to be changed back.

Is there any existing system to enable this tweak?

Answer (score 0):

Use `alias sudo="tput setaf 1; sudo"`.

To change the color back, simply add `tput setaf 0` to your `PROMPT_COMMAND` (in the `.bashrc`)